# How can I get a value from a nested Json String

Tags: jquery, json

I need to get a value from a JSON string. Here's the string :

```
[{
        "title": "T-shirt femme",
        "thumbnail": "http://www.donquishirt.fr/images/tshirtdesigns/thumbnail/1441979243_TMB_t-shirt-femme-vignette.png",
        "elements": [{
            "title": "Shirt",
            "source": "http://www.donquishirt.fr/images/tshirtdesigns/front/1439370862_womens_classic_basic.png",
            "parameters": {
                "x": 225,
                "y": 340,
                "z": -1,
                "opacity": 1,
                "originX": "center",
                "originY": "center",
                "scale": 1,
                "degree": 0,
                "price": 15,
                "colors": ["#f2f2f2", "#4ec1de", "#f05a9a", "#343434", "#f1730c", "#facde2"],
                "currentColor": false,
                "removable": false,
                "draggable": false,
                "rotatable": false,
                "resizable": false,
                "zChangeable": false,
                "boundingBox": false,
                "autoCenter": false,
                "replace": "",
                "boundingBoxClipping": false,
                "autoSelect": true,
                "topped": false,
                "flipX": false,
                "flipY": false,
                "colorPrices": {},
                "elementID": 27,
                "uploadZone": false,
                "filter": false,
                "filters": [],
                "isInitial": true,
                "source": "http://www.donquishirt.fr/images/tshirtdesigns/front/1439370862_womens_classic_basic.png"
            },
            "type": "image"
        }]
    }, {
        "title": "T-shirt femme (back)",
        "thumbnail": "http://www.donquishirt.fr/images/tshirtdesigns/back/1443879426_t-shirt-femme-dos.png",
        "elements": []
    }
```

I need to catch the value from "elementID" which is nested into "elements/parameters"

How can I do ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top-level data is an array, so you need to index that. Then `elements` contains an array, so you have to index it as well.

```
data[0].elements[0].parameters.elementID
```

If there are multiple top-level items and elements, you'll need to use nested loops to process them, and access.

```
data[i].elements[j].parameters.elementID
```

In general, it's simple to parse JSON. When you see `[` in the JSON, it's an array, and you index it with `[number]`. When you see `{`, it's an object, and you access properties with `.propname`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, that did the trick.

I just had to parse my object to a Javascript object before